# Where does the review status go under catkin?

Tags: newtags

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin complains that the `<review>` tag is not allowed in the `package.xml`.

Where should this information be maintained, now?

EDIT: I realize catkin does not support it. It is not needed for building.

The question is where does that information go? Is there now a wiki macro? Are we just throwing it away?

No reasonable user would consider this unimportant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55383/where-does-the-review-status-go-under-catkin?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that information is not maintained in catkin anymore, mostly because it has not proven to be useful. I cannot find the post where this was discussed, though.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-17**:
I remember the discussion. I can't find it, either. To me, review status is the *most* useful information about a package: if it has no reviews, it is not worth using.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-17**:
The value of the tag is worthless, as reviewed packages don't get their tag updated, packages which have been reviewed change and should be reviewed again, but are not, etc... the actual review status would be useful. That can be discussed in Buildsystem SiG, but prepare for disappointment.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-17**:
It is certainly *not* "worthless". The fact that a package that has *never* been reviewed is valuable information (i.e. don't use it). If the review date is present, but old, that is also useful to know.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-17**:
As I say, a tag saing "not reviewed" does not mean the package has not been reviewed. It would be foolish to put so much faith into a tag. And "reviewed 2009" does not tell you neither that it has not been reviewed in 2012. also the extend of the review is never known.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
I am not "putting faith" in a tag, just using it as evidence for Bayesian inference. It is quite unlikely that an reviewed package will say it is unreviewed. At the very least, that would be evidence of poor maintenance, and users should avoid it, if possible.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
The wiki Reviews page does document what reviews were done. Reasonable users can draw their own conclusions from the discussions recorded there.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-18**:
Thibault, I am confused by your assumption that a package with no 2012 review is worthless. The specific example for this question is camera1394. It is widely used and actively maintained. The last reviews were in 2010. The API and documentation have stable since then. Is that a problem?

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-18**:
This is no place for discussions.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I thought that, with the review tag going away, the review information, if valid, should go under `<exports>`.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-17**:
Seems reasonable.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-17**:
Not really. This means everyone has to invent their own style of putting this somewhere, making it impossible to machine-read the information. And the same problems exist as for the review tag, so it's worse in all respects.

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-02-18**:
i think part of the discussion was here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/ros-sig-buildsystem/GSHy2dI39gY/discussion , partly the review tag was discussed in a lengthy phone conference, the notes here http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/Reviews/2012-08-14_API_Review (not very verbose)